# How to change string case in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2013

I want to change case of a string in Excel. I am using MS 2013 suite.

I have checked various answers where people have suggested to use third party add-on or to user UPPER() or LOWER() function.

But it is tedious to use a function and I am not in a position to add a add-on to machine.

Can anyone please suggest any hot key(short cut key) to complete this requirement of mine.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "change case of a string" ? All uppercase or all lowercase?

Comment: @ moffeltje: My requirement is to change it all upper or all lower and also at time Initcap (First letter capital and rest being small).

Comment: Try this add-in https://aneejian.github.io/Change-Case-Excel-Add-In/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select a string (highlight). Go to menu and start recording a macro.

Do necessary action (ok that is nebulous).

Stop recording macro. Assign hotkey. Save macro.

Now next time, highlight something. Hit hotkey.

Note that later you can go in and modify the macro VBA code that you find for a particular solution

Comment: You can have a blast automating chained  actions as complicated as you want. http://howtouseexcel.net/how-to-uppercase-text-using-an-excel-macro-instead-of-the-upper-function

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Drew Pierce for seeding the idea of macro.

I have created the below macro:

```
Sub Change_Case()
'
' Macro change case
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+L

Dim Range1 As Range, cell As Range
Set Range1 = Selection
For Each cell In Range1
cell.Value = LCase(cell.Value)

Next cell
End Sub
```

And now with a short cut key(Ctrl+Shift+L) i am able to do my work.

Thanks again.

Comment: My pleasure writing macros for me was many years ago. They can be crazy complex, as in powerful

Comment: I've just tried to use this code and all it does is add a filter dropdown to the cells?? Like, *well* not what I was expecting.

Comment: I want to do this for a whole column at once. @Drew could this script be used for that?

Comment: I don't see why it could not be tweaked. Remember the Record aspect of what I wrote. Record a macro. Do stuff. Then stop recording. Look at what your actions wrote inside the macro. Replicate that logic.